# Collect Data from Text File

Tags: c++

I'm trying to read in data from a text file. How would I do that from C++. Do I have use the input mode?

```
open(fileName,ios::in)
```

If so, then how to I read in data, in string form?

Thanks

Comment: You should probably use [fstream](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_fstream)

Comment: Since this is for a school assignment I guess, is there any sort of support provided by your professor? There should be, I hope. Office hours? A virtual meeting place for the students in that course? I'm afraid that the best way to learn this is to get a book or look at online tutorials, but a lot of tutorial material is of the "blind leading the blind" kind and it's very hard for a novice to tell which is which :( This may be one viable starting point: https://github.com/tuvtran/project-based-learning

Answer (score 1):

This is the easiest way to do this:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

int main () {
    std::string str;
    std::vector<std::string> vec;

    std::ifstream myfile("example.txt"); //name of your txt file

    while (std::getline(myfile, str)) { // read txt file line by line into str 
        vec.push_back(str);  //you have to store the data of str
    }

    myfile.close(); // optional, streams are RAII types
                    // and thus close automatically on leaving scope
}
```